# Issue with Seaborn, not showing the values for Y axis in countplot

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I have the following dataframe (`ordered_recurrent_df`) which I wish to plot in Seaborn's countplot:

`ordered_recurrent_df`:

```
Month   Card
January     4
February    7
March      11
April      32
May        96
June      704
```

When I try plotting it using countplot, I get the following:

```
sns.countplot(data = ordered_recurrent_df, x = ordered_recurrent_df.index)
```

[image]

The same outcome occurs when I try transposing it, it seems to me is not taking into account the values from the "**Card**" column. Like if it only recognizes the values as labels, but that's it.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: You want a `barplot` : `sns.barplot(data=df, x='Month', y='Card')`, not a `countplot`, which is for the data before aggregation. You may want to specify an order for the `barplot`.

Answer (score 2):

`barplot` should work in your case:

```
ordered_recurrent_df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Month':['January','February','March', 'April', 'May', 'June'], 
     'Card':[4, 7, 11, 32, 96, 704]
    }
).set_index('Month')

sns.barplot(x='Month', y='Card', data=ordered_recurrent_df.reset_index())
```

N.B. I did set an index because in your `countplot` example you also used the `month` index.

[image]

`countplot` can be used when your data looks like:

```
ordered_recurrent_df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Month':['January','February','March', 'April', 'May', 'June'], 
     'Card':[range(4), range(7), range(11), range(32), range(96), range(704)]
    }
).set_index('Month').explode('Card')

sns.countplot(data = ordered_recurrent_df, x = ordered_recurrent_df.index)
```